# How can we add MySQL details as property in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

While creating a SparkSession, as there is a property to connect to Cassandra called

`.config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "ip-address")`

that can be directly added while creating a SparkSession, can we add the MySQL details similar to this so that we can avoid passing them in every Spark function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such option when connecting to MySQL. Cassandra has its own [spark-cassandra-connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) while for MySQL it uses [JDBC](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html) which requires the connection params to be passed as Java Properties.

They differ in configuration options and in how they works.